# Why don't I need to implement these abstract functions in C#?

Tags: c#, abstract-class

I am extending an abstract class Scene:

```
class IntroScene : Scene
{
    //
}
```

As you can see, it doesn't do anything.  The abstract class Scene has abstract functions:

```
public abstract void LoadContent(ContentManager content);
```

But, it's not complaining to me that I should implement them.  Why not?  This is what I'm used to.

I'm doing this in Visual Studio 2015, using the .NET framework 4.6.1.  Until recently I only worked in .NET 4.0.  Is this a change in the new C# 6.0 features, or am I missing something?

Comment: Are you sure `IntroScene` is derived from the `Scene` you are mentioning? Move cursor below `Scene` and press `F12`.

Comment: Instead of deriving just from `Scene` try using full type qualifier (i.e. including namespace - `YourNamespace.Scene`). If you derive from correct abstract class you will get a compile time exception

Comment: Post executable repro code. In the process of doing that you will find the answer yourself because there is no way this is true.

Comment: C# 6.0 does not talk about abstract classes, Also it has nothing to do with VS 2015 or .NET version. According to microsoft members with abstract keywod must be implemented in derived class. You are missing something. Please double check. or post at least Scene class definition.

Comment: Try this, click on scene and press Ctrl + . VS will show option to implement the abstract method. If it does not show, You may ne inheriting from a different class if not try to restart VS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Of course you are missing something.
Possible scenarios:

1. `Scene` in `class IntroScene : Scene` is not what it meant to be. Double check and make sure you are not deriving from different class. Specifying type by it's full name can help here.
2. `Scene` and `IntroScene` are in different assemblies or the compiler or visual studio has failed to track the changes in `Scene` or you forget to save the file which `Scene` is implemented in it or ... . You are referencing a wrong assembly which is not updated after you have made `Scene` abstract. Check references or build the project again.
3. Do not forget that we are software developers. Maybe it is a bug or a weird problem that no one has ever encountered and nobody knows how to reproduce it and the probability for facing it is very low. Try restarting visual studio or even your computer. Maybe even you need to get out of your room and enter again!

Comment: I apologize. I right clicked on Scene and used "Go to definition," and found that it was going to a newer version of Scene than the one I had opened and was looking inside.  I had downloaded multiple versions of the same library and was trying to upgrade from one to the other.  The new version still had Scene as an abstract class, but none of its members were abstract.